# Transforming Python list to networkx graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, networkx

Currently I have a list:

```
[['Мама мыть', 10, 'рама'],
 ['Мама мыть', 10, 'рама', 5, 'долго'],
 ['Мама мыть', 10, 'рама', 3, 'вчера'],
 ['Мама мыть', 10, 'рама', 3, 'вчера', 1, 'поздно']]
```

I need somehow to convert it to Networkx edges, where pairs of words should become nodes of the graph, and integers between become weights :

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('Мама мыть', 'рама', weight=10)
G.add_edge('рама', 'долго', weight=5)
G.add_edge('рама', 'вчера', weight=3)
G.add_edge('вчера', 'поздно', weight=1)
```

Currently I'm stuck and have no ideas. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do the elements in the list represent? There are more than 2 strings in some lists and you saw "pairs of words should become nodes"

Comment: Seems like there's a lot of repeated information in the list ('Мама мыть' to 'рама' with a weight of 10 appears 4 times for eg). Do you know for sure all occurrences will be consistent?

Comment: @JulienMarrec I was looking at the last item and thinking it's almost like a flattened version of nodes and weights... but yeah... pondering what if the first one was weight 12 and then that changed in the last entry...

Comment: @ninesalt Thanks for your reply. Each uniq pair should become node. Elements are just strings of text, it is for some NLP work.

Comment: @Alex is the intent that it's a multigraph?

Comment: @JulienMarrec Thanks for your reply. I need only unique pairs, as shown in wanted output.

Comment: @AlexNikitin what'd happen if your last item was ` ['Мама мыть', 10, 'рама', 3, 'вчера', 1, 'поздно']` instead of ` ['Мама мыть', 7, 'рама', 3, 'вчера', 1, 'поздно']` for instance though?

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for your reply. No, each node should have single connection. Shown output does all the job, I just need an algorithm to transform a list to Networkx add_edge format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have repeated information, I suggest starting by creating a dictionary to ensure uniqueness. I add a check to make sure you don't have conflicting distances for repeated elements.

```
In [1]:
distances = {}
for row in l:
    for i in range(0, len(row)-1, 2):
        key_tuple = (row[i], row[i+2])
        d = row[i+1]
        if key_tuple in distances.keys():
            if distances[key_tuple] != d:
                print("Warning: Found a conflicting distance for {}: {} and "
                      "{}. Using last".format(key_tuple, distances[key_tuple], d))
        distances[key_tuple] = d

In [2]: distances
Out[2]:
 {('Мама мыть', 'рама'): 10,
 ('рама', 'долго'): 5,
 ('рама', 'вчера'): 3,
 ('вчера', 'поздно'): 1}
```

Then you can create your edges using that dictionary.

```
In [3]:
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
for k, v in distances.items():
    G.add_edge(k[0], k[1], weight=v)
```

Comment: sure, `if (distances.get(key_tuple) is not None) and (distances.get(key_tuple) != d):` works too. That's cosmetic IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is really what I wanted.